# How many Strongholds are spawned in an Minecraft XBox map?

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

The [latest update](http://www.mojang.com/2012/10/new-minecraft-xbox-360-edition-update-is-out/) to Minecraft: Xbox 360 Edition added, among other things, Strongholds. In Minecraft for PC, only 3 strongholds appear per world (see the [Stronghold wiki article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stronghold)). But Xbox maps are limited and thus much much smaller than your average PC world.

Therefore, has it been revealed how many Strongholds will be spawned in an Xbox world?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this post](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1525103-strongholds/#entry18620547) by 4JSteve of 4JStudios:

> Strongholds are only in the Overworld (1 per level) and will take a bit of digging to find one.

Answer (score -1):

There is only one in a 500 block diameter of your spawn point.

Comment: Can you provide a source of this information?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by the radius? An XBox map is only 864 blocks across, meaning only a 432 block radius is possible.

Comment: Obviously, 500 block radius "inside the map boundary".