# How many Strongholds are there in Minecraft Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one, minecraft-legacy-console

A previous question ([How many Strongholds are spawned in an Minecraft XBox map?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89644/how-many-strongholds-are-spawned-in-an-minecraft-xbox-map)) states that there is only one Stronghold per map on the Xbox 360 edition. However the Xbox One edition supports much larger worlds; (5120×5120 as opposed to 864×864) does this mean there are more Strongholds on Xbox One Large maps, or is the limit still 1?

Answer (score 2):

It is still one.  The [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stronghold) states that for console versions there are only one:

> There is a limit of 128 strongholds per world (1 per world in Console Edition).

Another [forum](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/718567-minecraft-xbox-one-edition/70739807) confirms this (although the asker on that forum seems to not believe the person who answered despite their evidence).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a new stronghold on the most recent Xbox One Edition update and I found 4 different strongholds. So the wiki is incorrect at the time. (I don't believe it's been updated in a while.) So yes, not for large maps but on infinite size there are multiple. I believe the same as in Java.

Comment: You say you don't believe its been updated in a while, but why would it be? The game has not been updated for like 2-3 years.